# Git GUI - Branching misunderstanding

Tags: git, vscode-extensions, git-gui

I tried to understand the `Git GUI` but could not do it. Then I tried `VSCode` extension [Git History](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.githistory) but the problem is the same. Here's what I don't understand; This is a normal `Git GUI` branches:

[image]

Well, when I make a commit on another branch, say on a `dev`, the picture changes; As you can see the `main` vertical line goes to the right and the `dev` to the left, they change places:

[image]

This is very confusing. Why this happens? Please explain.

Maybe my misunderstanding is due to the fact that I associate `Git Graph` with a real tree:

[image]

Another question: is it possible to make sure that these vertical lines do not change places and remain in their places? (in `Git GUI` or in any `VSCode` extension).

Comment: Most recent commits are shown at the top. If the branch with the most recent commit changes.... the graph changes to reflect that. Why is it a problem?

Comment: Maybe my misunderstanding is due to the fact that I associate Git GUI with a real tree: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jakF2.jpg

Comment: I think the context you're missing is that branches "don't exist" in git. Branches are just pointers to commits. Commits don't know which branch(es) they are or were ever a "part of". There's zero difference in git between "main branching off dev" and "dev branching off main" --- both just mean that there's two commit (here `dev 1` and `main 2`) that have `main 1` are their parent.

Comment: and even the main branch of a tree does not have to be straight (https://snapinspire.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/crooked-tree-993x1024.jpg)

Comment: You shouldn't expect the tree view to remain fixed, as behind the scene the renderer logic/framework decides how to reorganize the branches. Rather normal if you use more Git clients. I don't think any Git client developer will spend time keeping branches fixed in spots, as that doesn't really add any value to the tooling.